# How to fix pdf "Failed to load PDF document." in chrome using mpdf

Tags: mpdf

I'm trying to view my downloaded PDF file from my website, but it shows this `Failed to load PDF document.` in all browser. Does anyone have any idea on this issue ?

```
<?php
        }
        $body = ob_get_clean();

        $body = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $body);
        $body = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT', $body);

        include("mpdf/mpdf.php");

        $mpdf=new \mPDF('+aCJK','A4','','' , 35, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        $mpdf->SetAutoFont();
        $mpdf->autoScriptToLang = true;
        $mpdf->autoLangToFont   = true;


        $stylesheet = file_get_contents('pdf.css'); // external css
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);


        $mpdf->WriteHTML($body);

        $mpdf->Output($_POST["id"]."_".$_POST["year"].'.pdf','D');

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Unless you provide the actual HTML and CSS code you are using, noone can help you. Try downloading the PDF file and opening it in a text editor to see any suspicious content. Also see https://mpdf.github.io/troubleshooting/corrupt-pdf-file.html and https://mpdf.github.io/troubleshooting/blank-screen.html

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly this issue. In seeking the solution, I observed in the browser inspector that I was getting a 404 response header, even though it was rendering the PDF in Firefox just fine. Apparently, Firefox just didn't care about that, and catches/renders the data anyway. Chrome, however, was being intransigent.

So I forced the issue:

```
http_response_code(200);
$mpdf->WriteHTML( $my_stylesheet, HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS );
$mpdf->WriteHTML( $my_html, HTMLParserMode::HTML_BODY );
```

This solved the problem for me.